# Can a Shiny app respond to a control without going to the server?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, rgl

I'm writing an `rgl` widget within the htmlwidgets framework so that `rgl` scenes can be used for output in Shiny apps.  Things are basically working (though it's still rough around the edges; see the `rglwidget` package on http://R-forge.r-project.org ), but it's not nearly as responsive as the native Javascript controls that are already in `rgl`.
I suspect the problem is the round trip to the server.

Sometimes this will be unavoidable:  if you want to make big changes to a scene, you may want to do a lot of calculations in R.  But in other cases (the ones covered by the native controls), there's no need for R to be involved, everything can be done in Javascript.

I don't want to duplicate all the work that has gone into writing the Shiny input controls, but I'd like to use them.  So my question is:

Is there a way to tell a Shiny input to call a Javascript function when it is changed, not to send its value to the server to be used in a Shiny output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question is "Yes"!  It's actually fairly straightforward, at least if the control uses the `htmlwidgets` framework.

Warning:  I'm not very experienced in Javascript, so this may not be very good Javascript style.  Please let me know if so, and I'll improve it.

Here's the idea:  If I have a Shiny `sliderInput()` control with `inputId = "foo"`, then my own Javascript code can get it using `window["foo"]`, and can set an "onchange" event handler on it.  When that event handler is triggered, I can read the "value" property, and send it to my controls.

If I don't use the reactive inputs from the slider, I don't get the delay from going to the server.

Here's my current renderValue function for the widget:

```
renderValue: function(el, x, instance) {
  var applyVals = function() {

    /* We might be running before the scene exists.  If so, it
       will have to apply our initial value. */

      var scene = window[x.sceneId].rglinstance;
      if (typeof scene !== "undefined") {
        scene.applyControls(x.controls);
        instance.initialized = true;
      } else {
        instance.controls = x.controls;
        instance.initialized = false;
      }
    };

  el.rglcontroller = instance;

  if (x.respondTo !== null) {
    var control = window[x.respondTo];
    if (typeof control !== "undefined") {
      var self = this, i, oldhandler = control.onchange;
      control.onchange = function() {
        for (i=0; i<x.controls.length; i++) {
          x.controls[i].value = control.value;
        }
        if (oldhandler !== null)
          oldhandler.call(this);
        applyVals();
      };
      control.onchange();
    }
  }
  applyVals();
},
```